# How to integrate Android GCM Pushnotification in Android Studio?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I need to integrate push-notification through GCM in my android app.
I have Tried some links but I could not understand that properly. Kindly help me to do this.

Comment: let us know what are the links u have been tried..?

Comment: I tried this https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Fallow this link is very useful for you https://trinitytuts.com/android-push-notification-using-gcm/

Comment: You can see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322631/adding-google-cloud-messagin-gcm-for-android-registration-process/32323334#32323334)

Answer (score 0):

With last update in Push notification google has come up with outstanding features specially for client side, now to implement push at client it need very less efforts, you need less lines of code.

For example they are providing configuration file which you add in your project then you don't need to add sender id in strings.xml

for reference have look

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Comment: Hi I tried this but i could not understand can you explain this bit more clear.

Comment: can you explain it by step by step? how to add that into project

Comment: They have provided all steps even they have also given git url for cloning so try that then post your issue if you faced.