# how to specify port number with ip for registering server for gcm

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

Hi i am trying to register my server ip for gcm notification.

My test server url was
 http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/mHealth_new/

and it was working fine...than i changed ip to live which is
  http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8086/mhealth_app/

but i cant configure this url with port 8086 it gives me error

[image]
please help me....

Comment: have you checked the port `8086` if it's already opened?

Comment: yes...i can access it

Comment: Try creating a new Server Key and API key for the production server. Then create a new Sender ID and register a device to test if it is working.  Here is a previous SO question related on [how to implement server for GCM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322631/adding-google-cloud-messagin-gcm-for-android-registration-process).

Answer (score 1):

In "Accept requests from these server IP addresses" section, you should fill the IP address of your current server, which is xxx.xx.xxx.xx. 8086 is the port number you use to access your server using http, not the port number used when your server sends the request to gcm server. The port that is used to send the request to gcm server is randomly assigned by the operating system.

Comment: but without port number...i cant get notifications

Comment: with the old ip i was getting notifications

Comment: By "i was getting notifications", did you mean you could get notifications on your server or on another device? From https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http and https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs, google doesn't use either port 80 or 8086 to send you notifications.

Comment: i can get notification on my android phone when i have registered with old ip

Comment: You should put in the IP address of your current server.

Comment: What are the response header and body you get when you send the request on your server?

Comment: i solved it by making public...removing ip address from it