# How to specify application server URL when setting up GCM in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I can't find this question answered (or addressed) anywhere else, so maybe I am just missing something really obvious, but I have followed [these official GCM steps](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start?configured) to get GCM added to my Android project and have got stuck.

My first issue is that the documentation states...

> ...copy the Server API key. Before running the app, you'll need to add this as the value of API_KEY in line 31 of GcmSender.java.

...but what/where is `GcmSender.java`?

And, my main question, how/where do I specify the URL of my application server in my Android project?

NB - I am using Android Studio. I haven't created my application server yet, but will be doing so with a PHP script that uses HTTP messaging.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is creating a new project at Google Developers Console . At this step, for simplicity, you just need to take note of 2 values: Project Number, which will be used as SENDER_ID in a client project; and API server key (created at Credentials), which will be used as API_KEY in a server project.

You can find more at my simple guide at the following questions:

[Adding Google Cloud Messagin (GCM) for Android - Registration process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322631/adding-google-cloud-messagin-gcm-for-android-registration-process/32323334#32323334)

[How to implement a GCM Hello World for Android using Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299997/how-to-implement-a-gcm-hello-world-for-android-using-android-studio)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks your help. In the end, I use the example files from https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services / .

Answer (score 0):

Have just found it.

In the `RegistrationIntentService.java` file, there is an empty `sendRegistrationToServer(String token)` method, so the URL of my application server (and the rest) needs to go in there.

Comment: NB - `RegistrationIntentService.java` is one of the GCM-related files that can be found in the example project at https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services .