# doInBackground method must return a result of type JSONObject

Tags: android

I am trying to implement `Asynctask` method with the combination of `GCM`  `JSONObject` in a sub class. I am having problems in applying the GCM condition in the `doinBackground` method.

Below is the a caption of the `doInBackground method`

```
 protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
     GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);
     final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);
     if (regId.equals("")) {        
        GCMRegistrar.register(context,SENDER_ID);
    }else {
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {               
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json =userFunction.registerUser(context,fname, lname, email, password,regId);
                return json;
        }
    }
 }
```

My IDE doesnt allow for it to be executed. This is the error message it gives.

> This method must return a result of type JSONObject

Now, when the return value is taken out of the conditions the codes above works correctly, However the return value is suppose to be executed only when the conditions are true.

**UPDATE**

There is another issue to this. `json` always return null in the doInBackground method because when GCM registrationID is empty the GCM Registrar registers it. As soon as it registers, then the GCM intent service takes over to do the server registration, this means that the `json` in the doInBackground would send null value to the `onPostExecute method`.

I also check for success and validation in the onPostExecute method. After checking for validaton, a message is sent to the UI.

If `json` send a null value to the `onPostExecute` method I cant do any validation and posting messages to the UI

Please is there a way around it to make the method above work, I would be 
grateful if someone could help. Thanks.

Comment: The method must return a value in all conditions. You should at least return  a null value at the end of the method.

Comment: You should put `return null` at last line or inside if (...)

Comment: For your update: IMO, you can refer to [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299997/how-to-implement-a-gcm-hello-world-for-android-using-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you defined the JSONObject. Try this -

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);
    JSONObject jsonObject = null; //Declaration
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        GCMRegistrar.register(context,SENDER_ID);
    }else {
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            jsonObject =userFunction.registerUser(context,fname, lname, email, password,regId);

        }
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

Now in your onPostExecute() just check that if your JSONObject is null or not before start accessing the data -

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    if(jsonObject != null) {
        //Do something i.e. access data
    } else {
        //Handle null JSON
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, please there is a problem to this, kindly check my question, i have updated it. Thanks

Comment: As I can see you are using GCMRegister which is deprecated. You should be using GoogleCloudMessaging as GCMRegister block things and has to be put into AsyncTask. Try porting to GoogleCloudMessaging. It will make your life lot easier.

Comment: Indeed GoogleCloudMessaging made my life very easy, Thanks sooo much @Varundroid

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a variable outside, and return it.

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

    JSONObject json = null;

    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);

    if (regId.equals("")) {        
       GCMRegistrar.register(context,SENDER_ID);
    } else {
       if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {               
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } else {
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            json = userFunction.registerUser(context,fname, lname, email, password,regId);
       }
    }

    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `return null` if there is nothing to pass back.

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

    // declare it here
    JSONObject json = null;
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);
    if (regId.equals("")) {        
        GCMRegistrar.register(context,SENDER_ID);
    }else {
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {               
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            json =userFunction.registerUser(context,fname, lname, email, password,regId);
        }
    }

    // if the criteria isn't met then return the null object reference
    return json;
}
```

then just do a null reference check in `onPostExecute()`.

If you are telling the method to return something of a certain type then you need to do that. You just need to always think ahead about if the object can be `null`