# I am trying to integrate GCM push notification into my app, but some errors are occurring

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have followed this tutorial

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

My logcat shows error

```
10-05 21:25:05.154 443-498/com.example.shashi.pushnotification E/GMPM: 
    getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
10-05 21:25:05.156 443-498/com.example.shashi.pushnotification E/GMPM: 
    Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
10-05 21:26:02.572 443-1181/com.example.shashi.pushnotification E/GCMRegistrar: 
    internal error: retry receiver class not set yet
10-05 21:26:44.331 443-1181/com.example.shashi.pushnotification E/shiashi GCM:
    Failed to register on attempt 1:java.io.IOException: Post failed with error code 500
10-05 21:26:47.309 443-1181/com.example.shashi.pushnotification E/URL:
     > http://shashi8600.esy.es/gcm/register.php
```

Comment: Pls take a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932935/sending-push-notification-using-google-gcm/32940082#32940082) in which you will find 2 working links to my sample code, hope this helps

Comment: Very old tutorial and uses deprecated service. You should opt for the newer GCM implementation as explained here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/