# Access needed to a GCM API project

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

We have a GCM API project key that we use in our Android application and a week ago we had lost access to it. It was either deleted or it was created by an employee who is no longer with us. How do we get access to this API project which is attached to our company domain?

Comment: Can you clarify more? Please read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489862/google-gcm-token-vs-registration-id/33490670#33490670 and tell `GCM API project key` is what in that link

Comment: In what circumstances did the employee leave? Are you sure that your company owns the code, contractually or legally speaking? (I ask because this may in reality be a legal dispute rather than a technical problem).