# What is the difference between of Firebase Cloud Messaging token and Server key?

Tags: php, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]

Just wondering what is the difference of the credentials above? I tired using both which is working. Im using PHP backend API to send FCM notifications to targeted devices.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:

Referring to @FrankvanPuffelen's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37671576/4625829):

> we'll soon revert to calling that value a server key, since calling it a token just introduces more confusion.

This pretty much verifies that there isn't any difference to it.

---

No difference at all. Nothing mentioned in the docs about it either.

It's just that the FCM token is now the value that is being encouraged to use instead of the Server Key, since as mentioned in the note (visible in the image):

> ...support is being deprecated for Server Keys.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase console now shows the following message:

> Firebase has upgraded our server keys to a new version. You may continue to use your Legacy server key, but we recommend that you upgrade to the newest version.

It does look like Firebase wants you to switch your credentials.  The new credential has Server key like before, but your old credential is now labeled as a "Legacy Server key".

So it looks like Firebase did, in fact, walk back on their calling it a token.