# FCM with Postman - The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token)

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

[image]

//body its like this

```
{
    "to":
    "/topics/NEWS"
    ,
    "data":{
        "extra_information": "This is some extra information"
    },
```

//notification that i need to give

```
"notification":{
            "title": "ChitChat Group",
            "text": "You may have new messages",
            "click_action":"ChatActivity"
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62670409/1151916

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The 401 error pertains that your Authorization Key is invalid or incorrect.

When using Postman, add a `key=` prefix for the value of Authorization, like so:

```
key=AAA...
```

See below for a tutorial on Sending Downstream FCM Messages using Postman.

Also, for your `notification` message payload, `text` isn't one of the valid parameters, I think you were looking for `message` instead.

---

---

**Sending Downstream Messages using Postman**

To do this in [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en), you simply have to set the following:

1. Set request type to `POST`
2. In the *Headers*, set the following:

   - Content-Type = application/json
   - Authorization = < Your FCM Server Key > (See your [Firebase Console's Cloud Messaging Tab](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging))
3. Set the payload parameters in the *Body* (*in this example, we used the *raw* option, see screenshot (2)*)
4. Send the request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Screenshots:

(1)
[image]

**Note**: Always keep your Server Key a secret. Only a portion of my key is visible here so it should be fine.

(2)
[image]

(3)
[image]

Notice that the request was a success with the `message_id` in the response.

Comment: Thank you @AL. you saved my tons of recherche to read! It's a pitty that `Postman` isn't a resource in the documentation of `Firebase`... I'm working under `windows` and there is no `cURL` built in!

Comment: @webprogrammer You're welcome. :) Actually, the instructions I made used to be in the StackOverflow documentation, but the service closed a few months ago. I guess there are a lot of options available and Firebase doesn't want to seem like they're being biased with a service. Cheers!

Comment: After sending notification from firebase console, if the app is not in foreground it won't receive in `onMessageReceived` method of  `MyFirebaseMessagingService.java` class. Tapping that notification, It will take us to launcher activity. From there we have to call this `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` url using retrofit, passing what data we have received in launcher activity. And after that response will hit the `onMessageReceived` method of `MyFirebaseMessagingService.java` class. Is it correct?@AL.

Comment: @AL. get message_id but not created in fcm notification history and  also not received notification

Comment: Hi, Can you please look at my question regarding firebase https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523615/firebase-trace-showing-wrong-median-time-latency

Comment: Hi! I also didn't receive the message but found out that changing the body message on screenshot 2 the push arrived to the phone
`{
  "to" : "<my token>",
  "data" : {
    "body":"Message...",
    "title":"title..",
    "score":"880",
    "time":"02:45"
  }
}`

Comment: how to send topic notifications from postman?

Answer (score 22):

Wrong:

> Authorization:AIzaSyDDk77PRpvfhh......

Correct:

> Authorization:key=AIzaSyDDk77PRpvfhh......

Full example:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

Comment: Yes! My time was completely wasted by Google trash docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options with wrong "token" insead of correct "to"...

Answer (score 6):

While the answers above are still correct, you may choose to use HTTP v1. This requires `Bearer` instead of `key=` and uses an Oauth2 access token instead of a server key string. To view HTTP v1 specifications, please refer to the link below:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

Comment: The google docs are trash. have been through them for days now and the code is mixed up between the two apis

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting same error in PHP , solved with below header :

```
$header = array("authorization: key=" .  $this->apiKey . "","content-type: application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Miss the `key=`, when using Postman to `firebase` push notifications always
add `key=` as prefix of key.
ex:  `key= AAA...`