# How to use fcm(firebase cloud messaging) with scala play framework to send notification?

Tags: scala, firebase, playframework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use fcm (firebase cloud messaging) to create web push notification, so I started by creating my project on firebase than I got the API key that I added to the HTTP header request, I used wsClient offered by play to send POST HTTP request to the firebase endpoints, But I got the error 401, I tried to use server key, legacy key but it is always the same result.

```
def sendNotification()={
var  url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
val request: WSRequest = ws.url(url)
  .withHttpHeaders("Authorization"->s" $myserverKey","Content-Type" ->"application/json")
val data = Json.obj()
val futureResponse = request.post(data)
Await.result(futureResponse, Duration.Inf)
Logger.warn(s"send notification to firebase $futureResponse")
```

error message:

```
401: The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token). Please, 
refer to section "Authentication" of the FCM documentation, at 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309674/fcm-with-postman-the-request-was-missing-an-authentication-key-fcm-token/45310143. Gut feeling is that you're missing the `key=` prefix in the value.

Comment: it works, but I got a failure response :
    "error": "InvalidRegistration" 
what could be the cause?

Comment: That's a different problem, meaning that the token your using is not known to the FCM server. Search Stack Overflow for the error message and you should get some good his.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not following the protocol for putting the server key in the Authorization header.  According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize_http_requests), it should look like this:

```
Authorization: key=YOUR-KEY
```