# C# FCM : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, firebase-cloud-messaging

In postman **WebAPI** is working fine but when i tried to use it in code it always return message :

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

here is the code  :

```
            var payload = new
            {
                to = deviceId,
                notification = new
                {
                    body = "Test",
                    title = "Test",
                },
                data = new
                {
                    message = "Hello, hows you?"
                }
            };

            var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
            using (var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"))
            {
                httpRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "key=" + applicationID);
                httpRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sender", "id=" + SENDER_ID);
                httpRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
                httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);
                    //400 - bad Request
                }
            }
```

fyi (applicationId = serverkey)

Comment: var payload = new
                {
                    to = deviceId,
                    notification = new
                    {
                        body = "Test",
                        title = "Test",
                    },
                    data = new
                    {
                        message = "Hello, hows you?"
                    }
                };

                var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

Comment: I think the error is in the payload, can you put it from the comment in the question and formatted correctly? can you also dump the `result` HttpResponseMessage completely?

Comment: same payload tried with postman and it works.

Comment: can you put it from the comment in the question and formatted correctly? can you also dump the result HttpResponseMessage completely?

Comment: question updated. and SendAsync throws an exception : An error occurred while sending the request., Inner Exception : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.,Status : Protocol Error

Comment: can you explore the result object a bit deeper? usually you'll find some hints why the request was considered bad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184952/discussion-between-dhaval-thakkar-and-falco-alexander).

Comment: The `SenderId` is not necessary to complete a Downstream Message request, just the `Authorization` which must have your Server Key. If that still doesn't work, could you try sending the request [using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45310143/4625829) and see if it still throws an error?

Comment: have you resolved your issue? I am getting same error

Answer (score 1):

If not exist `deviceId` on FCM server you will have `(400) Bad Request`.

In your `FirebaseService` `onNewToken` method, send token to your server and use it for push.