# Not able to get token using FCM in android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am following a tutorial i.e. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

but I am not able to get token nor my service class are working. Please help

Comment: have you registered your service in Manifest.xml ?

Comment: yes , i did......

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the : "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:X.X.X" dependency?

you can refer to this post for more info : [What is FCM token in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671380/what-is-fcm-token-in-firebase)