# GCM API key, registration ids to third party server

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

How safe to provide GCM API key and GCM registration keys to third party servers (other than internal servers) ? Also, Do I need to create new API key for 3rd party server ?  I need to understand how an untrusted server can misuse the GCM registration key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FCM Security: Prevent multiple senders from pushing notifications to all devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523967/fcm-security-prevent-multiple-senders-from-pushing-notifications-to-all-devices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide the GCM API Key to a third party server, this server will be able to

1. send notifications to the GCM registrations ids
2. send notifications to topics
3. subscribe / unsubscribe GCM registrations ids to topics

You can create a GCM API Key for every server,
so that you can invalidate it when your trust relationships ends.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create API keys for every server, so that GCM will respond to only those server which were listed on your console