# How to get registration key Firebase?

Tags: firebase, key, firebase-cloud-messaging, registration

**Firebase** allows us to send notification messages via our own application by making `POST` request.

This tutorial gives instructions how to make this request. However, there is a `"to"` field in the **JSON**, where I must place a **Registration key**.

Where can I get this **Registration key**? There are no instructions for this.

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "data" : {
    ...
  },
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is FCM token in Firebase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671380/what-is-fcm-token-in-firebase)

Comment: I guess the Firebase crew isn't answering questions anymore. I also have this question. The documentation is inadequate.

Answer (score 0):

To get a token, call `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();`. After that step, in order to see the token, just make an output to **Logcat**

**Code example:**

```
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
Log.i("MainActivity", "Token: " + token);
```