# Get Internal Server Error for Get Information About App Instance

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I try to send Get Request in Postman in the Url
'https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/IID_TOKEN', it gives me Internal Server Error.

The IID_TOKEN I get is from FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) Server Key.
The YOUR_API_KEY I get is from FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) Legacy Server Key.

Am I sending the correct IID_TOKEN and YOUR_API_KEY? Or is it any authorization that I have not done?

Please help me on this.
Thank you.

Comment: [Instance ID token = FCM/Registration token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37671576/4625829)

Answer (score 0):

How you obtain the IID_TOKEN depends on the client SDK you are using.  In the [Cloud Messaging Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), the section for each client SDK (e.g. iOS, Android, Web, etc) has a topic titled *Send Your First Message* with a step describing how to obtain the registration token.  For example, the [Android description](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message#retrieve-the-current-registration-token) says to use  `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`.

From your post, it sounds like you are using a server key, which is not correct.

There is an example GET request in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#example_get_request).