# What API to enable in GoogleAPI to use InstanceId service?

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use batchImport to map apns to FCM token. 
The server documents in google speaks about using

https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/

https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_registration_tokens_for_apns_tokens

but there the heck is iid (InstanceId) service.Anyone?

Comment: The *instance Id tokens* in the sample is referring to the `registrationToken`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37671576/4625829

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is FCM token in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671380/what-is-fcm-token-in-firebase)