# node js FCM Send notifications to multiple users at once

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building cloud notifications based on Firebase. We are currently working on creating a server as node js and controlling cloud notifications.

However, I have searched a lot of data, and most of the above data is transmitted to only one person by receiving the token value when sending notifications.

Of course, i can use mysql to send it to a large number of people, but is it possible to send it to all users who have the app installed as a user segment like the Firebase console?

Here is the site I referenced. I made it using the script provided here.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but is it possible to send it to all users who have the app installed as a user segment like the Firebase console?

Not possible out of box. You need a user's [registration token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671380/what-is-fcm-token-in-firebase) to do any sort of messaging. If you do not have all your user's registration tokens, then you'll need to retrieve it for each user. Remember to verify the tokens *before* persisting them to your database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

And as the readme states for `fcm-node`:

> Warning: on February 2, 2017, the Firebase Team released the admin.messaging() service to their node.js admin module. **This new service makes this module kind of deprecated**

With that said, you have two options:

1. Send notifications to multiple users via their registration token:

-

```
const registrationTokens = [
  'abc',
  'efg',
  '123'
];

const message = {
  data: {
    score: '850'
  },
  token: registrationToken
};

const promises = [];

registrationTokens.forEach(token => {
  const promise = admin.messaging().send(message);
  promises.push(promise);
});

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(results => console.log(results))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

1. Or better yet, use [Topic Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging) on a  *"user segment"*. You'll need to subscribe users to their respective topic. For example, Android documentation on how to do that can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic)

-

```
const message = {
  data: {
    score: '850'
  },
  topic: 'myUserSegmentTopic'
};

admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .error(err => console.error(err));
```