# Can my phone receive Firebase push notification if I have installed an app that support it but I have never open it before

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Do I need to open the app at least once in order for my phone to receive a push notification?

Comment: you need to run your app at least one time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The must run at least once so it can collect a device ID token and send that to the backend that will send the message.  Without that token collected, the app can never receive a message on that device.

Read more about it: [What is FCM token in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671380/what-is-fcm-token-in-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not need the device token to send/receive the messages.

However, it is required that the user give permission to receive notifications, and that would only happen during runtime. I tested this and can confirm it works. The device token is only used to subscribe users to specific topics, but you can send a message to all users that have your app installed without needing to specify device tokens.