# FCM intermittenly generates wrong token

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried to search the solutions everywhere, like several links below but couldn't find any correct answer.

[FCM token Not Generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67832320/fcm-token-not-generating)

[What is FCM token in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671380/what-is-fcm-token-in-firebase/37671576#37671576)

[Firebase FCM force onTokenRefresh() to be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454501/firebase-fcm-force-ontokenrefresh-to-be-called?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The problem is every time I tried doing fresh install, both from Android Studio and Play Store, FCM sometimes generates a right token, but sometimes it generarates a wrong token. Whilst the right token is always different, the wrong token is always the same, starting with `eyJhb`. I know this info is useless since FCM generates the token based on device ID and app ID.

I've forced FCM to generate the token using this code in my `LoginActivity.java`:

```
mPrefToken = getSharedPreferences(PREF_TOKEN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fcmtoken = mPrefToken.getString(KEY_TOKEN, "");
if (fcmtoken.equals("")) {
    FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstallationTokenResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstallationTokenResult> task) {
            if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                return;
            }
            fcmtoken = task.getResult().getToken();
            mPrefToken.edit().putString(KEY_TOKEN, fcmtoken).apply();
            sendToken(user_id,fcmtoken);
        }
    });
} else {
    sendToken(user_id,fcmtoken);
}
```

And in `MyFirebaseMessagingService.java`

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
    super.onNewToken(token);
    mPrefToken = getSharedPreferences(PREF_TOKEN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mPrefToken.edit().putString(KEY_TOKEN, token).apply();
}
```

I'm using the latest Android Studio (4.2.2 and build gradle `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2`) but have been experiencing this issue since 4.1.x as far as I can remember. My app is targeting SDK 23 - 30.

I'm using `buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"` but I believe I've been experiencing this since 30.0.2

FCM version is `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0`. Have tried with 21.0.0 but experienced the same thing.

Comment: Starting with `ey` seems to be a JWT, and not an FCM token. I don't think `FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getToken(true)` returns JWTs, so are you sure those values aren't coming from somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Because the shared preferences file got written in `onNewToken()` method inside FirebaseMessagingService. Besides I'm not using JWT at all. Just heard about it now.

Comment: We are facing the same issue, did you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same issue. Currently it seams that this alternative solution using FirebaseMessaging provides the correct FCM token in my case so far.

```
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener((r) -> {
        if(r.isSuccessful()){
            String fcmToken = r.getResult();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass `.getToken(true)` refresh, but `.getToken(false)` refresh.