# Why I'm unable to fetch an api using axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am learning backend development can you help me to hit an api? I tried doing something like this but it's not hitting the API also it's not logging "Making API call" I tried to console log expirationDate, token, and email and they three logs correctly but still it's not hitting the API and not logging Making API call What's wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Also No error In the console

Also I am using node-schedule and the value of expirationDate, token, and email look like this

```
2023-03-30T01:48:46.962Z dsvicPH1SSOCdHWpxrMrvF:APA91bFYXRKOsa2F_JTYkEOLiPM32o1NoWDi2fgE_vssum3csYJt_kLRZK9BfARoogQ7Q3xxWeFREo3J4ms_MEZYPGo_bEWlVZzG-kEJC_juw8fvw8J3OXiJNE4w0owjiAuIHWOcRhsR idsdsdd@gmail.com
```

The Token is a FCM token [What is FCM token in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671380/what-is-fcm-token-in-firebase)

```
function scheduleApiCall(expirationDate, token, email) {
    console.log(expirationDate, token, email)
    // Schedule the API call to be made at the specified date and time
    const job = schedule.scheduleJob(expirationDate, async function () {
        // This function will run at the specified date and time
        // Make the API call here
        console.log('Making API call');
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(
                'http://localhost:3000/getnoti',
                {
                    title: 'SERVER NOTIFICATION',
                    body: 'I am coming from server',
                    token: token
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }
            );
            console.log(response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });

    // job.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing an ending quotation mark and how are you calling `scheduleApiCall `?

Comment: @justDan i edited it i did mistake while editing on StackOverflow in my code editor its right

Comment: @justDan scheduleApiCall(expirationDate, token, email)

Comment: does `console.log('Making API call');` get executed?

Comment: @v0rs4 as i mentioned in the post I cant see any  console.log('Making API call');

Comment: how about this console log `console.log(expirationDate, token, email)`? If not, then the function `scheduleApiCall`  is not invoked. If yes, then the job scheduler is not working as expected

Comment: @v0rs4 please check my edited post i think its problem with that

Comment: what's the reasoning behind using `node-schedule`?

Comment: @v0rs4 the reason to use node-schedule is on expirationDate i want to send a notification to my users

Comment: is this `expirationDate` string or `Date` object?

Comment: @v0rs4 its a object 2023-03-30T01:48:46.962Z

Comment: ok, so if `expirationDate` is a `Date` object and it's set in the future then I don't know what I'm missing :(

Comment: @v0rs4 So I guess you mean that  "Making API call" will log in the future before hitting the API? Is there any way that I can check its status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading `node-schedule` documentation, you're not passing *expiration* date as the first argument, but just date (or schedule). Copying-pasting from the docs:

> Say you very specifically want a function to execute at 5:30am on December 21, 2012. Remember - in JavaScript - 0 - January, 11 - December.

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const date = new Date(2012, 11, 21, 5, 30, 0);

const job = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
  console.log('The world is going to end today.');
});
```

Basically, you scheduled the job "do it exactly at 2023-03-30T01:48:46.962Z" (which, as of now, is a date several hours in the future).

https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule#readme

Comment: So my code is not wrong?

Comment: @hack I see no other apparent issues besides that date. Change this argument to sth like "two seconds from now" and you'll know.