# Google Cloud Messaging returns Failure: HTTP Status Code: 401

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using online tool to send Notification to my Device

1. http://gcm-alert.appspot.com/
2. http://techzog.com/development/gcm-notification-test-tool-android/

They both returns,

> Failure: HTTP Status Code: 401 -Unauthorized

I have followed following steps to implement Google Clound Messaging API

1. Create Configuration File added it in my Project->app Folder
2. Created `Async Task` In Main Activity and write Following Code.

   SharedPreferences getPreference= getSharedPreferences("GCMToken", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           String tokenID= getPreference.getString("tokenID","");

   ```
       if(tokenID.isEmpty()) {
           InstanceID gcmTokenistanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
           token = gcmTokenistanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.project_id),
                   GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
           GCMServiceURL= "MyWebServerURL.com/="+token;
           Log.i("TOKEN From IF Condition", token);
           saveTokenID(token);
   ```
3. Then I created NotificationService and extend this class with GcmListenerService

public class GCMNotificationService extends GcmListenerService {

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("Test Message from Server");
    NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText(message);
    notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
```

**Manifest File**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="com.app.myapp.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.app.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />



<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.app.myapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>


<service
    android:name="com.app.myapp.GCMNotificationService" android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: how does your manifest look like?

Comment: @SalvatoryBaya: I have updated my question

Comment: how about the permissions?

Comment: @SalvatoryBaya:Question Updated

Comment: In permission i am providing Root package name, under myapp i have another folder `services` which contains NotificationClass ..Do i need to provide full package name or it is enough

Comment: Try as my sample project at https://github.com/ngocchung/GCMAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Kirmani88 What type of API Key are you using?

Comment: I am using the senderId provided in Configuration File as API key

Comment: @BNK :: Thanks for the Link. Will your project work if i try to send notification using it?

Comment: https://github.com/ngocchung/GCMAndroid is my client app, it's working with https://github.com/ngocchung/gcmserver the server app, I am not sure with your server apps, you can try

Comment: @BNK : I have import your project, added a new configuration file and tried it running on online `GCM-Notification-Tools`, Its still giving me `Unauthorized Error 401`. I changed nothing in your code, Just add configuration file and a key. Kindly guide me

Comment: I have tried with `http://gcm-alert.appspot.com/`, my client app can receive the message. I think you should provide the correct information, please take a look at my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489862/google-gcm-token-vs-registration-id/33490670#33490670

Comment: @BNK : I have asked a question, kindly review it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984993/google-cloude-messaging-returns-error-401-unauthorized

Answer (score 1):

Add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```