# Android Studio cannot resolve MyGcmListenerService symbol

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to setup Google Cloud Messaging between an Android app (Android Studio) and a server. I'm following the directions here: [Set up a GCM Client App on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest). The code below is what I've added to my manifest file (as instructed).

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service
    android:name="com.example.MyGcmListenerService"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
    android:name="com.example.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

This is probably a simple question, but I cannot figure out what `com.example.MyGcmListenerService` and `com.example.MyInstanceIDListenerService` should be. Android Studio says these symbols are not found. I have not found any help online or on the same instructions page as to what these values should be.

**Do these values refer to classes I need to create? Do they refer to something local or remote?** I have installed the required SDK components and Cloud Messaging tools (the `com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver` *does* get resolved).

Sorry if this is obvious. I am new to Android Studio.

Comment: Have you set `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"` in your build.gradle file yet?

Comment: Yes, I've included `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0"`, which imports just the GCM components. I assumed `MyGcmListenerService` is just a placeholder for something since it starts with `My`. Is this how I should leave it? If not, what should go here?

Comment: I suggest you read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299997/how-to-implement-a-gcm-hello-world-for-android-using-android-studio, hope it helps!

Comment: You can see that your `com.example.MyGcmListenerService` is equivalent to my `.GcmService` in my sample

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at that now, thanks. I'm going to create another class then.

Comment: One question @BNK, did you not need to create a service to handle the registration token, as here? [See here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) This seems to say this is required in order for the client to receive messages.

Comment: The registration token got at client app, you should send it to the server app so that server app can send messages to client app. You can read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322631/adding-google-cloud-messagin-gcm-for-android-registration-process

Comment: In my 1st link, you can see in server-app `final String CLIENT_REG_ID = "..."; //An ID issued by the GCM connection servers to the client app that allows it to receive messages` that is the registration token of client app

Comment: You can refer to my 2 server/client sample projects at https://github.com/ngocchung/GCMAndroid and https://github.com/ngocchung/GCMServer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97087/discussion-between-thatwiseguy-and-bnk).